# How can i do public ajax call?

Tags: ajax, urls

I need to know exactly how the AJAX URL REQUEST works in wordpress

my code :

php (in function.php):

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_search_widget', 'wpa56343_search_widget'); // for not logged in users
    add_action('wp_ajax_wpa56343_search_widget', 'wpa56343_search_widget');
    function wpa56343_search_widget()
    {
      global $wp_query;
      $search = $_POST['query'];
      
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            //'posts_per_page' => -1,
            's' => $search,
            'posts_per_page' => 20,
            /*'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                 'taxonomy' => 'category',
                 'field'    => 'term_id',
                 'terms'    => '1',
                 ),
                ),*/
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     
      if($wp_query->have_posts())
 while($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            
    <h1>do some html work</h1>          
          
        <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
              //endif;
              die();
    }
```

my simple SCRIPT code

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#s-mobileapp').keypress(function(event){
          
           var query = $(this).val(); 
                      
           if(query.length > 2)  
           {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action:'wpa56343_search_widget_mobileapp', 
                        query:query,
                    },
                    success:function(data){  
                        $('#searchwidgetresult-mobileapp').html(data);
                        $('#searchwidgetresultcontainer-mobileapp').css({"display":"block","border":"1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187)","box-shadow":"0px 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"});
                    }
                    });
           }else{
            $('#searchwidgetresult-mobileapp').html('');
            $('#searchwidgetresultcontainer-mobileapp').hide();

           }
      }).blur(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#searchwidgetresultcontainer-mobileapp').hide()
                    }, 500);
                }).focus(function() {
                    $('#searchwidgetresultcontainer-mobileapp').show();
                });
});
```

The problem is these functions works good in some pages and some not.

when i test the SCRIPT code by alert i found that the code stops in the ajax url call

```
  url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
```

so is there any other way for this url method ?

something like public ajax call ?

> Please Note :
>
> To make things clear these pages aren't native wordpress pages, they
> are custom pages that i made with php, the path of these pages is
> the_permalink()/page1 and he_permalink()/page1/page2, page 1 is
> working fine but page 2 isn't

Comment: to make things clear these pages aren't native wordpress pages, they are custom pages that i made with php, the path of these pages is the_permalink()/page1 and he_permalink()/page1/page2, page 1 is working fine but page 2 isn't

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/380048/edit) to add context, rather than adding it here in the comments.

Comment: I suspect the issue is your `admin-ajax.php` path...  try using this: `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );`... ...but IF these files are operating outside of WordPress then they won't know what that URL is... ...so at the top of your file, declare the path to the site rather than using `./wp-admin/`... ...or even write a mysqli query to get the site URL and concatenate it all with the path to admin-ajax.php.